# Assignment of class property from child vs calling super, is there any significant difference?

Tags: java

I'm new to java so you'll have to excuse my ignorance.

Is there any meaningful difference between implicitly setting a value to a class property from a parent class as opposed to using a constructor and calling `super`.

I don't think I explained properly what I mean so here's a concrete example

```
public class Parent {
    protected String name;
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public Child() {
        this.name = "Child";
    }
}
```

As opposed to

```
public class Parent {
    protected String name;

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public Child() {
        super("Child");
    }
}
```

This code, essentially, does the same thing. If setters/getters would exist in either parent or child they'd work pretty much how you'd expect them to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both your examples creating a `Child` object via `new Child();` would result in a Child object with the `String name` field set to `"Child"`.

Constructor chaining is usually done to make code more maintainable and avoid duplicate code. eG Let's say instead of using a fixed value the `String name` attribute would be an argument that would have to be passed into the constructor. And we also would like to disallow `null` values for the `String name` attribute and throw an error if a user tries to create an Object by passing `null` into the constructor.

Without constructor chaining and calling `super(name)` you would end up with code like this:

```
public class Parent {
    protected String name;

    public Parent(String name) {
        if(name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be null!");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public Child(String name) {
        if(name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be null!");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

While if you use Constructor chaining you would not have to write duplicate code as you can put all logic into Parent constructor that is always called:

```
public class Parent {
    protected String name;

    public Parent(String name) {
        if(name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name cannot be null!");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    public Child(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. Basically it boils down to "depends" and "use your best judgement given the situation". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly mentioned this code do the same thing. However, in that particular case there is some related one to each other advantages of using `public Parent(String name)`:

- It gives you an ability to mark field `String name` final, what is actually meant to be in that case.
- It's more straightforward: you probably expect `Parent` class to have `name` defined, so it shouldn't depend on how `Child` class is implemented, or whether it even exists.
- It would implement basic OOP principle: encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite abstract, so my answer will also be abstract :)

As you pointed out, for this particular implementation it doesn't really matter, technically you're doing the same. But you may have some logic of how you assign the field (although, I'm personally against any logic in the constructor, besides the fields assignment). E. g. You may like to "clean up" your `name`, by replacing the trailing spaces etc. or to check if the name is valid or not null, then it would be beneficial to have it in the parent class, so none of subclasses can mess the logic up. That means that your second example better suites this case. It maybe opposite, when you need to make some special cleanup in the child, but not in the parent, then the first example is better. That's from practical perspective.

My personal opinion is that the second example is better, because it generally makes code more simple. I usually even try to avoid setters and make the field `final`, or maybe even private. In another words, if this `name` field belongs to the `Parent`, then let parent assign it and don't try to intervene. Then every time when you see that `name` is wrong, or you need to somehow change the logic of how you assigning the name, you know one and only place where to do that. Maybe tomorrow you'll decide to introduce two additional fields for conveniency `firstName` and `lastName` and the logic will be like: split the name with a space and assign first and last name. If you go with the first example, you will need to duplicate this logic. In the second example, you just hook into `Parent`'s constructor.